# Make iPhone specific App work on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift3

When Creating my iPhone specific game it works fine on all iPhone screens (iPhone 5-iPhone 7+)

I submitted the app to the app store but Apple have rejected it saying that some scenes were crowded and not displaying correctly.

On iPhone: [image]
Notice that all button are displayed on screen.

Whilst on iPad Air: [image]

I am completely stuck on what to do. I have set the App to iPhone Specific on xCode so why is is displaying differently?

My Scenes are 1334 x 750px which is the default for iPhone 6+ in Landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

If your app has Only iPhone device support not universal, And app is correctly designed for all iPhones it should work with iPad as well with @1x and @2x mode

iPad normally takes the design of iPhone 4 to render on screen i.e. 320x480, and you supported iPhone 5-iPhone 7+ it is not rendering on iPad devices.

So you should give support your design for 320 x 480 or iPhone 4 as well.

**Update**

An easy option is Embed your current view within scroll view and make is scrollable only with height 480.

Add a ScrollView just below your viewcontroller root view and all existing subviews within scroll view and make it scrollable with device height 480 (also set content size manually or automatically)

Comment: Thanks for that information, i was not aware that it used the iPhone 4 size as a rendering on the iPad... Ive gone round in so many circles and changes so many things i am not lost haha.

How can i add support for 320x480?

Comment: Easy option is Embed your current view within scroll view and make is scrollable only with height 480

Comment: Im abit of a beginner in Swift, Might need a little walkthrough. Hopefully it will work and i can upvote! :)

Comment: It's not about Swift or upvote, it is design part constraints or frame part.

Comment: Oh okay so its not something i need to code in? How can i make it embed my current view like you said above?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to of fixed this issue by changing the scenes to .aspectFit from .aspectFill